# set image button background dynamically

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have defined array of `ImageButton` dynamically and that will take its buttons background from the user selected photos, my problem is that when I restart the app, the image buttons does not stay, how can I make it stay "along with the user selected background for it" without define it in the XML? I think of shared preferences but I am not sure if it will solve the problem!

```
icon[count]= new ImageButton(this);
icon[count].setImageResource(R.drawable.p1);
icon[count].setImageBitmap(photo);
```

Comment: I think with shared preferences it´s the easiest and fastest way, so just store it there...

Comment: But you mean background color or image?

Answer (score 0):

To save Background color you have applied , Shared preferences is perfect solution.

*You need to save state of background color and retrieve it when you are restarting app(onRestart()) or onPause() or onResume().*

> how can I make it stay "along with the user selected background for
>   it" without define it in the XML?

**Using Shared preferences**

Checkout [Android Shared preferences example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23024962/2826147)

Comment: it is image background not just color .shared preferences solve the problem too?if yes can you help me how to make that?

Comment: yes, you can. check another example http://androidopentutorials.com/android-how-to-store-list-of-values-in-sharedpreferences/